# saving athena results to another table with partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

From AWS Athena

I am trying to concatenate multiple tables then save it with partitoned key.

after running

```
select *
  from t1
union all
select *
  from t2
select *
  from t3
```

create table on the console creates query like this,

```
create table db.table_name
with(
format='parquet',
external_location=...
) AS
select *
  from t1
union all
select *
  from t2
select *
  from t3;
```

But I want to add partitoned by column. I've tried

adding partitioned by on top and bottom. Also saved query result then created new table from that using `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` command (this works but return empty row -> even after running `MSCK REPAIR`)

From https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-create-use-partitioned-tables/ It seems like I need to save data into S3 by partitions so in bucket1 it will have bucket1/2021, bucket1/2022 if 'year' column is the partition column. Correct? If yes, is there efficient to create partitioned buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully created new, partitioned tables by using this method:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
WITH (
 format = 'PARQUET',
 parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
 external_location = 's3://bucket/folder/',
 partitioned_by = ARRAY['year']
)
AS
SELECT
  ...
```

Comment: Oh, Couldn't find how to add partition key when using `CTAS`. Thanks!